# iframe a page into a site hosted by a third party

Tags: iframe

Looking to integrate a basic iframe into a website not hosted by me and wondering what are the risks and things I need to ask the other party to do who are managing the website? Also, their site is responsive and my page isn't, so when their site scales down for mobile and tablet, they want to replace my page (because it's not responsive) within an image. Is it JavaScript that just changes the DOM depending on screen size and so in a conditional statement will just show up either an i-frame tag or image src tag in the html? help!

Comment: Are you adding someone else's webpage into your own webpage using iframe?

Comment: the other way round, they are adding my webpage into their site